# Is it possible to create multi column combobox by subclassing only its listbox?

Tags: mfc

In MFC, is it possible to create multi column combobox by subclassing only its listbox.

In Codeproject and Codeguru websites I got samples only with derived CComboBox with ownerdraw style.

Comment: And why don't you want to use them? Tell us the reason why you are asking when there are existing solutions!

Comment: In my application, If I use CComboBox with ownerdraw I need to make many changes in the code.If it is achievable by subclassing only its listbox, code change will be less for that reason only I asked.

Comment: Using the MFC it should be complicated to just replace the classname and subclass. What more changes do you expect? Of course you have to write code to show the data you want... but more?

Answer (score 1):

The "list" part of a combo-box control is NOT a list-box control. Apart from this, combo-box controls do not really have "columns", and this means that you cannot store column-level data (there is just one string or "item" per row), and subsequently any solution visually imitating "columns" can only be owner-drawn-based. So, if your app's specs have changed (now requiring column formatting) you should rather consider using another control type. Still, an owner-draw implementation isn't really that hard, esp if you have fixed height items; it shouldn't really require extensive changes to your app, as it concerns this specific control only.